# Using Sinon to cause Redis to expire a key

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I'm writing a mocha test for some task and I want to check value B 3 minutes after function A returns. So, I'm looking for something that helps me change the time because I don't actually want to wait 3 minutes.
I need to check whether a confirmation code is removed after 3 minutes or not, I have this line in my Redis database:

```
RedisClient.expire(data._id, 180);
```

and in my test file I have a test :

```
it('should send a confirmation code for: 00989130000963', function (done) {
        api
            .post(settings.UserRegister)
            .set("ping-client", "M")
            .set("type","register")
            .expect(200)
            .send(postData)
            .end(function (err, res, body) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                if (res.body.result === "WAIT") {
                    if (res.body.confirmHeader !== "") {
                        clock.tick(180*1000 + 100)
                        console.log(clock)
                        done();
                    }
                    throw new Error("no header set");
                } else {
                    throw new Error("not in the wait state");
                }
            });
```

but clock.tick doesn't work as expected.After this test a user should be able to request for confirmation code again, because old one should be deleted, but It seems that the old one is still in Redis.

Comment: Do you have some code to show us?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order for people to help you, make sure to put in some of your working out (e.g. your code) into the question, showing the work you already did. Then we will be more likely to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

The Redis server is a process *external to Node*. The only thing that Sinon can affect is how the code *in Node* sees the clock provided by Node. It does not affect how Redis sees the clock. So you cannot force Redis to expire a key with Sinon.

What you could do is enable your code to set a different, shorter, expiration value in testing. Or simulate the expiration of the key by deleting the key in your test code.